# strategies increase number of objects in an application

Tags: design-patterns

Can someone please elaborate the following related to strategy pattern:

"Strategies increase the number of objects in an application. Sometimes you can reduce this      overhead by implementing strategies as stateless objects that contexts can share. Any residual state is maintained by the context, which passes it in each request to the Strategy
object. Shared strategies should not maintain state across invocations."

Why do strategies increase number of objects in an application ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens only as mentioned when you maintain the state of the strategies.
Let me explain it a bit more :
Say you have a class StandardCalculator. Now suppose you have an APIs (alias strategies) for following operations

1. Add two numbers
2. Get square root of a sum of square of two numbers i.r square_root(a_square + b+square)
3. Difference of two numbers

Now there are two ways to achieve solution :
1) Have a constructor which accepts two numbers
2) Client creates the instance and then calls getSum(), get_square_root_sum(), get_difference() etc.

In this case whenever a client needs to use these APIs it will need to create a new instance of StandardCalculator

Other solution is :

1. Create a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) class

   1. Have APIs getSum(int a , int b), get_square_root_sum(int a, int b), get_difference(int a, int b) etc.

So here your APIs ask for parameters to perform strategy implementation on.

In this case different clients can use the same instance of StandardCalculator to call different strategies.